# Deployment of boilerplate with asp.net core and angular 2 application

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-boilerplate

I am trying to deploy boilerplate framework asp.net core with angular2 application in IIS and localDB. I am not aware of deployment. can you please give me the steps for the same.

Thanks in advance.